# set values after form submit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and have a form for add transfers. I have written validation rules in the controller but when the form submitted the errors message appear but the form forget the values which was entered by the user.

I try to use set_value and it works but sometimes I want to make if statements and I think it mus be in the controller not in the view. Is there a way to make the set value in the controller and return it in $data to the view

> view

```
<?php $type_val= set_value('type');  ?>
<select class="form-control show-tick" id="type" name="type">
    <option value="<?=set_value('type');?>" ><?=($type_val == 1) ? 'Exit' : 'Come';?></option>
    <option value="1">Exit</option>
    <option value="2">COME</option>                         
 </select>
```

> controller

```
public function add(){

if($this->input->post('submit')){

$rules = $this->get_rules_validation();
$this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $data['title'] = 'Add Transfer';
            $data['view'] = 'admin/transfer/transfer_add';
            $data['validation_error'] = true;
            $this->load->view('layout', $data);
        }
        else{
            $data = array(
                'type' => $this->input->post('type'),

            );
            $data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);
            $result = $this->transfer_model->add_transfer($data);
            if($result){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Transfer is Added Successfully!');
                redirect(base_url('admin/transfer'));                   
            }
            else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Transfer Cant Be added!');
            redirect(base_url('admin/transfer'));
            }

        }
    }
    else{
        $data['title'] = 'Add Transfer';
        $data['view'] = 'admin/transfer/transfer_add';
        $this->load->view('layout', $data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Samira, There is no such a way to `set_value` in the controller. However, you can check the posted value and mark it as selected and pass in the `$data` but you have to check again that value to show an option as selection in the view that will make no sense.

And you should use `set_select` instead of `set_value`.

For example

```
<select class="form-control show-tick" id="type" name="type">
  <option value="1" <?php echo  set_select('type', '1'); ?>>Exit</option>
  <option value="2" <?php echo  set_select('type', '2'); ?>>COME</option>                         
</select>
```

You can see full documentation here. [Set select codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/form_helper.html#set_select)

One more thing, you don't need to load view twice. You can load it only once.

`$this->form_validation->run()` will execute only when your form is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

i have put the validation in a function instead

```
public function get_rules_validation(){
    $rules = array(
        array(
                'field' => 'type',
                'label' => 'Type',
                'rules' => 'is_natural_no_zero',
                'errors' => array(
                    'is_natural_no_zero' => 'You must provide a %s.',
                ),              
        );
       return $rules;
       }
```

add

```
public function add(){

if($this->input->post('submit')){

$rules = $this->get_rules_validation();
$this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $data['title'] = 'Add Transfer';
            $data['view'] = 'admin/transfer/transfer_add';
            $data['validation_error'] = true;
            $this->load->view('layout', $data);
        }
        else{
            $data = array(

                'created_at' => date('Y-m-d : h:m:s'),
            );
            $data = $this->security->xss_clean($data);
            $result = $this->transfer_model->add_transfer($data);
            if($result){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Transfer is Added Successfully!');
                redirect(base_url('admin/transfer'));                   
            }
            else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Transfer Cant Be added!');
            redirect(base_url('admin/transfer'));
            }

        }
    }
    else{
        $data['title'] = 'Add Transfer';
        $data['view'] = 'admin/transfer/transfer_add';
        $this->load->view('layout', $data);
    }
}
```